# How to make UINavigationItem rightBarButtonItem badge number updates immediately after the number changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

In objective c, I used third party chat sdk to make an IM software, I have a main viewController and another chatlist viewController, and the third party chat sdk has a delegate function that can check whether I receive the message or not. Which function is:

```
- (void)onRCIMReceiveMessage:(RCMessage *)message left:(int)left {}
```

[image]

In ViewController A, I am able to execute the function above. So In that function I did

```
- (void)onRCIMReceiveMessage:(RCMessage *)message left:(int)left {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.badgeValue = @"2";
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

but the problem is ViewController A did not change at all, only after I click the button to ViewController B and back it will change, so how can I update the navigation baritembutton in viewController itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to update your left bar button item and not right.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.badgeValue = @"2";
```

Comment: Yes, sorry it is just the typo, but still not working

Comment: I am assuming you are using custom navigation item to have the `badgeValue` property. Could you please put a break point in your `drawRect` method and check if it gets triggered with your `[self.view setNeedsDisplay]` call.

Comment: @Abinav it's not get into that function.

Comment: Thats the issue. I am sure you are not calling `setNeedsDisplay` on right object. Can you please call it on the object that draws your badge. For instance, if your view class is `BadgeView` than ensure you call `setNeedsDisplay` on `BadgeView` and not on `self.view`. There might be a indirect way to forward this call to your `BadgeView` like from your view controller to pass it to your custom view.